# Android : Add random data with different images and proper text

Tags: java, android

I am working on a demo android app. Currently, I have a list of products which I am displaying, but they all have same image and the text generated is also random characters generated with Java method. Needless to say, it doesn't look very good.

I am using an adapter and displaying the data. How can I `efficiently` use random images(either from URL or from a selected folder), and names from some XML file to make the UI look better.

Code :

```
public class Products extends Activity{


    ProductAdapter productAdapter;
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    public static final String productName = "productName";
    public static final String productComments = "productComments";
    public static final String productLikes = "productLikes";
    public static final String productDescription = "productDescription";
    public static final String userName = "userName";
    ListView productsList;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        for(int i=1;i<100;i++){
            Product product = createProduct();
            productList.add(product);

        }

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsArrayHashList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Product product : productList){
            HashMap<String,String> productDisplay = new HashMap<>();
            productDisplay.put(productName,product.getName());
            productDisplay.put(productComments,String.valueOf(product.getCommentCount()));
            productDisplay.put(productLikes,String.valueOf(product.getLikes()));
            productDisplay.put(productDescription,product.getDescription());
            productDisplay.put(userName,new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
            productsArrayHashList.add(productDisplay);
        }

        productsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productList);
        productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this,productsArrayHashList);

        productsList.setAdapter(productAdapter);

}

    public Product createProduct(){
        int minimum = 1;
        int maxValue = 20;
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setCommentCount(minimum + random.nextInt(maxValue - minimum + 1));
        product.setLikes(minimum + random.nextInt(maxValue - minimum + 1));
        product.setSaveDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        product.setDescription(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
        product.setName(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
        product.setSize(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
        if(getRandomBoolean()) {
            product.setSold(true);
        }else {
            product.setSold(false);
        }
        return product;
    }
```

Adapter code :

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public ProductAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
            TextView productName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            TextView userUploader = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.uploadingUser);
            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.productStars);
            TextView comments = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            TextView productDetails = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            ImageView prodImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
            prodImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.productwatch);
            HashMap<String, String> productList;
            productList = data.get(position);
            productName.setText(productList.get(Products.productName));
            comments.setText("Comments("+productList.get(Products.productComments)+")");
            productDetails.setText(productList.get(Products.productDescription));
            userUploader.setText(productList.get(Products.userName));
            int minimum = 1;
            int maxValue = 5;
            ratingBar.setRating((float) (minimum + random.nextInt(maxValue - minimum + 1)));
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.

You'll need Picasso library for Android

Add this line to build.gradle under `dependancies`

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

In your Adapter code, add this after initializing your ImageView.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext)
    .load("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/")
    .into(imageView);`
```

For more info : [Picasso - Github](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

The numbers after that URL are the dimensions, you can specify suitable dimensions.

I used http://lorempixel.com/ (Visit it to explore more features)

You can use any site to get the images.

Comment: When I use Picaso, I get only some tree images. I used a thread, and got random images. Thank you. Any suggestions for tag and text?

Comment: Go to that website, you have categories there, use that URL. For tag you can just use a randomize function. For text, copy words (separated by commas) and put it in a String Array. Randomize the index and get the string.